# "e umlaut" not correct shown in html mail

Tags: php

I have a problem with e umlaut (ë) in html mail.

This is the piece of code where the country is being checked in a selectbox:

```
// selectbox country
if($_POST['country'] == 'nederland') {
$country = 'Nederland';
}
else {
$country = 'België';
}
```

I use these headers for the email:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email;
```

This is my mail command:

```
$formsent = mail($ontvanger, $onderwerp, $body, $headers);
```

Result:

Gmail gives me on Belgie just 1 dot (in stead of 2 for e umlaut like normal)

Online webmail (in holland) gives me a question mark in a black box on the place where e umlaut should be

Ziggo webmail ( in holland) gives a perfect e umlaut

What is wrong? the wrong headers?

Answer (score 0):

Is your PHP script saved as UTF-8? If so, this is why - and two of the three providers are doing it right by taking your header literally.

This may shed some light:

```
 $country = mb_convert_encoding('België','iso-8859-1');
```

Comment: I would add the third parameter: `, 'utf-8'` since this is not always the default encoding.

Comment: @ComFreek: valid point, though if he is dutch and running on windows, he may not necessarily have his source in utf-8 to start with - possibly another subset of iso.

Comment: Problem is solved! The main issue was that i am using HTML-kit 292 as editor and when i save a file, he does not save it as utf-encoded file. I noticed that when i used another editor and put the file on the webserver. When i submitted a test-text with special character, all the email clients gave me a perfect output. Anyway, thank you very much for support!